# twitter api v2 expansion field option returns less data than the endpoint

Tags: python, twitter

```
user_data = 'user.fields=description,location,name,public_metrics,username,verified'
expand = 'expansions=author_id'
tag = 'new zealand -is:retweet'
url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query={}&{}&{}".format(tag, expand, user_data)
```

so this is the way I organized my request, let say the maximum number of data I want from this endpoint is 20, I can use the expansion field to get additional data about the tweet author, the problem is the expansion field payload does not match the default data return by the endpoint. for example, If the endpoint returns 20 tweets the expansion field also returns 20 fields, but in my case sometimes I get just 1, any help, please...

API response sample

```
  data part
    {'data': [{'id': '1341144983215239170',
       'lang': 'en',
       'created_at': '2020-12-21T22:14:15.000Z',
       'text': "@chrissy99912291 Is it because he's neo? When DJ cuppy said she needs iPhone 12 no one dragged her, why y'all pressed? What kind of mentality is this?",
       'author_id': '1268532525321932803',
       'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 0,
        'reply_count': 0,
        'like_count': 0,
        'quote_count': 0}},
```

include['user] part

```
{'username': 'AOmozoya',
    'description': "I'm gifted",
    'id': '1102564893071429633',
    'verified': False,
    'location': 'xx, xx,
    'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 64,
     'following_count': 383,
     'tweet_count': 608,
     'listed_count': 0},
    'name': 'Special_miracle'},
```

the length of the two response was supposed to be equal for this particular response when i try to check the length of both like this. data is the name of the json response.

```
len(data['data'])
>>100
```

whiles

```
len(data['includes']['user'])
>>32
```

user data is supposed to correspond with each tweets.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you mean here?

Comment: @AndyPiper  I have added the sample result, please do take a look, thanks

Comment: Are the same users represented more than once?

Comment: No, i don't think so, i will have to cross check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to get to the bottom of this issue without more details on the users that are returned.

However, I would recommend the package [`osometweet`](https://github.com/osome-iu/osometweet/tree/master). It is currently in development, however, the [search branch](https://github.com/osome-iu/osometweet/tree/search) has a search method which you can pass your query to with the expansion parameters that you're interested in.

Check out the [wiki](https://github.com/osome-iu/osometweet/wiki) which has a lot of instructions.

- [Authentication](https://github.com/osome-iu/osometweet/wiki/Method:-Authentication)
- [Search Method](https://github.com/osome-iu/osometweet/wiki/Method:-Search-Endpoints)
- [Managing fields and expansions](https://github.com/osome-iu/osometweet/wiki/Method:-Specifying-fields-and-expansions)

Answer (score 1):

That's because it does not correspond to the number of tweets.

If suppose, a user is common in some of the tweets,
then user is present only once.